# How can I make a navbar icon link easier to press in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I've added a link to the trailing edge of my navbar using the following code:

```
bodyContent
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        NavigationLink(
            destination: InfoView()
        ) {
            Image(systemName: "info.circle")
        }
    )
```

This code works, however I'm finding that it's difficult for the user to press (testing on an iPhone X) due to a small selectable area.

Using the view debugger, I believe this small rectangle within the circular icon is the selectable area:

[image: info icon]

How can I increase the size of this area, at least so that it is as large as the circular icon? Ideally the user would be able to press anywhere above and below the icon as well, within the vertical space occupied by the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add padding

```
bodyContent
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        NavigationLink(
            destination: InfoView()
        ) {
            Image(systemName: "info.circle").padding() // << here !!
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Padding the trailing edge offsets the icon, so I went with this:
 `.padding([.leading, .top, .bottom])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a 
.frame(width: 100, height: 100)

and it will be clickable in the entire space, though other UI elements will act as if your icon is that size.